# How to parameterize the surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$ for $z\in [0,1]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Express the surface using two distinct parameterization methods where
$x^2+y^2=z^2$ for $z\in [0,1]$

Ans: I can parametrize it as $$\vec r(t,z)=(z\cos(t), z \sin(t), z)$$ for  $z\in [0,1]$ and $t\in [0, 2\pi]$.

Another parameterization may be as follows
$$ \vec r(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$$
**but how to define the ranges of $u$ and $v$**? Is there any other possible parameterization?

Answer (score 1):

You are rewriting your surface as the graph of a function. Your surface in question is a cone. If you look it from above/below, you see a disk of radius $1$, without holes: this means that the domain of your graph (i.e. the range of $(u,v)$) is $(u,v) \in \{ (x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$.

Having a visual understanding of your surface helps.